# Where is simple exponential relaxation in relation to graph theory?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm studying relaxation in the Ising model. Let me describe my model from a physics perspective. Let's say we have $n$ spins in one dimension, e.g.  ${\hat s_o=(\uparrow,\downarrow,...
\text{n times}....\uparrow)}$. I'm going to leave out interactions because they aren't relevant to my question.  With each increment of time $t$, I will flip one randomly selected spin.  Let $\hat s(t)$ denote the state of the system at time $t$, then let me define the relaxation as $\hat s_o \cdot \hat s(t)/n$.  My physics intuition tells me that in the limit  of a large system this relaxation behaves like simple exponential decay $\text{exp}(-t/n)$, give or take factors of $2$. Indeed, you can easily calculate this relaxation numerically with a computer, and you can achieve simple exponential relaxation to any desired precision by choosing a large enough $n$.

Next, I'll to switch to a math perspective.  In math, the non-interacting Ising model with single spin flip dynamics is equivalent to a random walk on a  hypercube of dimension $n$.  I'm new to graph theory, but I have been studying mixing times in a simple graph and I've made it as far as Cheegers inequality.

To my question: Why don't I see a calculation of simple exponential relaxation on a hypercube in graph theory?

In a physics approach, simple exponential relaxation in a noninteracting Ising model is a simple, obvious result. Why isn't it an obvious result in the field of graph theory?  I can't seem to find the bridge between the two approaches.

Thanks.

Update: I think I'm getting close to an answer.  There is a paper by https://www.researchgate.net/publication/235197003_Spectral_Graph_Theory_of_the_Hypercube which studies the eigenvalues of the $n$ hypercube.  I think that the relaxation of the Ising model corresponds to the fastest Eigenvalue and this holds in the limit of large  $n$.

Comment: Let $X_k$ be the expected number of spin that have not change sign at time $k$. You could write down the recursive formula between $X_{k+1}$ and $X_k$. This lead to a equation which should give a geometric decay (and hence exponential decay).